# Does Salesforce charge for Apex callouts on Enterprise version?

Tags: callout, enterprise, pricing

**Does Salesforce charge for Apex callouts on Enterprise version?** Maybe a certain number of callouts is free, but after that it's not?
We're adding a new trigger that will fire an Apex callout each time someone updates a Lead.
We have a lot of leads in the org, so I'm wondering if this trigger creates additional fees for the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the number of callouts allowed in your org in System overview (Setup > Quick Search > System Overview)

If you cross this you will have to pay to get more callouts.

Detailed documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

Comment: Check the detailed documentation (link added) you will get exact idea.